# Flex 4 Combo - using IME

Tags: flex4, ime

I am trying to use ime (for hiragana input) in a flex 4 spark combo.
On creation complete I am setting the following.

```
cbx_text.textInput.imeMode = IMEConversionMode.JAPANESE_HIRAGANA;
```

And to check, tracing the following:

```
trace(cbx_text.textInput.enableIME); returns true;
trace(cbx_text.textInput.imeMode); returns JAPANESE_HIRAGANA;
```

However, when I select the text input and start to type some text I am unable to switch to hiragana.

I can set it to work on a textinput component with no problems.

```
<s:TextInput imeMode="JAPANESE_HIRAGANA"></s:TextInput>
```

Has anyone had any experience with this?
Any insights much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Although I haven't had any experience with IME, I took a quick look at the documentation : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/IME.html

Can it be that it's not enabled application wise? That, maybe what returns true is only valid for the component you are tracing from?

Answer (score 1):

Obvious questions first:

Are you certain the TextInput is a member of cbx_text? I know this seems silly, but it's best to eliminate the obvious first.

Do you have an IME enabled on your computer? For example, do you regularly type in hiragana on your computer and have the appropriate language pack enabled?

Are you sending the IME the string appropriately? `IME.setCompositionString()` for windows computers?

Does your OS support the use of IMEs? Linux only supports the following methods:

- `Capabilities.hasIME`
- `IME.enabled` <= Can set or return value.

Try tracing `hasIME` and see if it's installed. Again, we're shotgunning here – trying to track down any possibility of a problem.

When all else fails, go to the source:

- http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=18_Client_System_Environment_6.html